# Wormhole in React typescript does not render anything: createPortal + useContext

Tags: reactjs, typescript

[This is the corresponding playground.](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-sea-i89pl9?file=/src/index.tsx)

**Goal:** Basically, I want all children of `PortalEntrance` to be rendered under `PortalExit`.

**Basic idea:**

- `PortalProvider` provides a `ref`
- `PortalExit` assigns the `ref` to one its children
- `PortalEntrance` uses the `ref` for the 2nd argument to [createPortal](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/createPortal)

---

For completeness, here is the complete playground code:

```js
import type { ReactNode } from "react";
import * as React from "react";
import { createPortal, render } from "react-dom";

type PortalContextType = {
  ref: React.MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement>;
};

const PortalContext = React.createContext<PortalContextType>({
  ref: null
});

type PortalProviderProps = {
  children: ReactNode;
};

function PortalProvider({ children }: PortalProviderProps) {
  const ref = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const value = React.useMemo(() => ({ ref }), [ref]);

  return (
    <PortalContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</PortalContext.Provider>
  );
}

function PortalExit() {
  const { ref } = React.useContext(PortalContext);

  return <div ref={ref}></div>;
}

type PortalEntranceProps = {
  children: ReactNode;
};

function PortalEntrance({ children }: PortalEntranceProps) {
  const { ref } = React.useContext(PortalContext);

  if (ref.current === null) {
    return <></>;
  }

  return createPortal(children, ref.current);
}

function App() {
  return (
    <PortalProvider>
      <div style={{ border: "1px solid green" }}>
        <PortalExit />
      </div>
      <div style={{ border: "1px solid red" }}>
        <PortalEntrance>my content</PortalEntrance>
      </div>
    </PortalProvider>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming it should render "my content" message, right? If so - I have a solution.

The issue comes from `ref` and how rendering is handled by React. React re-renders the component if a state of some sort updates. How is this an issue?

Refs, on the first render, are `null` and only then obtain their value (reference) after the initial render but that does NOT trigger a re-render.

When you put these 2 together - your component `PortalEntrance` does not update. You have a logic that if `ref.current` is `null` then render an empty fragment. else - render a createPortal.

```
function PortalEntrance({ children }: PortalEntranceProps) {
  const { ref } = React.useContext(PortalContext);

  if (ref.current === null) {
    return <></>;
  }

  return createPortal(children, ref.current);
}
```

So on the first render `ref` is `null` so it goes into the if. After the initial render - `ref` is no longer `null` BUT nothing triggers a re-render.

Even tho it does not cause a re-render, the `useEffect` hook can still catch its value changing. Using that, you can change the state yourself forcing to re-render the component.

In the `PortalEntrance` component, create a `useState` like `const [hasRef, setHasRef] = React.useState(false);`. Before the `if`, create a `useEffect` that is listening to the ref like so

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    setHasRef(!!ref.current);
  }, [ref]);
```

And change your `if` statement to check `hasRef` rather than `ref.current` for rendering an empty fragment.

Your component should look like so:

```
function PortalEntrance({ children }: PortalEntranceProps) {
  const { ref } = React.useContext(PortalContext);

  const [hasRef, setHasRef] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setHasRef(!!ref.current);
  }, [ref]);

  if (!hasRef) {
    return <></>;
  }

  return createPortal(children, ref.current);
}
```

This does the trick. Working fork example: https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-field-7zi1pm?file=/src/index.tsx:769-1093